# "no schema has been selected to create in" even after opening up postgres permissions

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

```
diesel migration list
Failed with: no schema has been selected to create in
```

This is the error I'm trying to solve. I recently made some changes to roles and permissions in Postgres, and now my diesel migrations won't run.

```
cat .env
```

The result shows that indexer1 is the pg user.

But I've looked at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106067/18098 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207259/no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in-error and even opened up the permissions as much as I know how (temporarily sacrificing security).

```
postgres=# show search_path ;
   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
 \dn+ public 
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | indexer1=UC/postgres+| 
        |          | =UC/postgres         | 
(1 row)

 \du
                                        List of roles
     Role name      |                         Attributes                         | Member of  
--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 editor             | Cannot login                                               | {}
 indexer1           | Create DB                                                  | {}
 postgres           | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 readonly           | Cannot login                                               | {}
```

(I've omitted some additional roles that I think are irrelevant.)

### UPDATE

I temporarily ran:

```
ALTER USER indexer1 WITH SUPERUSER;
\du
```

and now `diesel migration list` works.

But my question remains because this indexer1 user didn't need to be a superuser before.

What else should I check and adjust?

### RESPONSE to first comment

What does the following result tell us?

```
\connect mainnet_node;
You are now connected to database "mainnet_node" as user "postgres".
mainnet_node=# show search_path ;
 search_path 
-------------
 public
(1 row)
mainnet_node=# \dn+ public 
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | editor=UC/postgres  +| 
        |          | readonly=U/postgres  | 
(1 row)

mainnet_node=# grant usage on schema public to indexer1;
GRANT
mainnet_node=# grant create on schema public to indexer1;
GRANT
mainnet_node=# \dn+ public 
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | editor=UC/postgres  +| 
        |          | readonly=U/postgres +| 
        |          | indexer1=UC/postgres | 
(1 row)
```

If I remove superuser from indexer1 now, will I probably be "back to normal"?

Comment: The error you show is not a permissions issue.  It happens when search_path is empty, or is set only to schemas which don't exist.  If the schema exists but you don't have permissions, that would give a different error message.  Presumably the search_path you showed is for a connection other than the one experiencing the problem.

Comment: @jjanes Interesting. Thank you! I updated the question above. You may have figured it out.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, I think that solved it. If you write an answer, I'll mark as accepted! Thanks. After `ALTER USER indexer1 nosuperuser;`, `diesel migration list` still works! 